# VBA code for skipping the full+empty cells and get the last full cell value and transfer for another sheet

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am trying to find out a VBA code for the following problem. I need to a VBA code which matches the name on sheet1 with breaklist and copy and paste last table(T) number to sheet one? the time slots on breaklist sheet are just for display purposes they are not real time cells.

**BreakList**

[image]

**Sheet1**

[image]

Comment: Have you made a start on the VBA code you need? It would be helpful to see a more specific statement of what you're stuck on.

Comment: so B2 on Sheet1 would be what?

Comment: Scott Craner- B2 needs to be T4, A2 needs to be T5 and D2 needs to be X. Thanks

Comment: so you want the last filled cell in that row?

Comment: halfer- No, i haven't start yet, i found some codes but not specifically address my problem. Thanks.

Comment: Scott Craner- Yes, and every time when Break-list updated need to find last cell and copy-paste to sheet 1.

Comment: @RALF: when replying to folks here, please use their handle e.g. `@halfer`, so they are notified. Tab auto-complete is available. Thanks.

Comment: In relation to the question, it may close as "too broad". Readers have an expectation that some effort has been expended prior to posting, so that free-work requests are somewhat discouraged.

Comment: @halfer Sorry wasn't know about that and thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @halfer: I did try many times but did not get result. i just tried and delete it. on my next questions i will post my work as well. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

formula:

```
=INDEX(INDEX(breaklist!C:I,MATCH(A2,breaklist!B:B,0),0),MATCH("zzz",INDEX(breaklist!C:I,MATCH(A2,breaklist!B:B,0),0)))
```

Put this in Cell B2 then copy down.

[image]